# How to use IF/CASE statement in stored procedure WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure like this

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `shashiTest`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `shashiTest`(IN GroupId INT, IN UserId INT, IN ChapterId INT)
BEGIN
    select 
    sum(qptdq.mark)-sum(qpe.marks) as marks_detucted,
    count(qpe.tc_question_message_type_id) AS noof_errors,
    (SELECT tqmt.key_value from tc_question_message_type tqmt WHERE tqmt.id=qpe.tc_question_message_type_id) AS error_type
    from question_paper qp
    INNER JOIN question_paper_group_student_map qpgsm ON qpgsm.question_paper_id=qp.id
    INNER JOIN institute_group_student_map igsm ON igsm.id=qpgsm.institute_group_student_map_id AND igsm.group_id=GroupId AND igsm.user_id=UserId
    INNER JOIN question_paper_template_detail qptd ON qptd.question_paper_template_id=qp.question_paper_template_id
    INNER JOIN question_paper_template_detail_question qptdq ON qptdq.question_paper_template_detail_id=qptd.id
    INNER JOIN question_paper_details qpd ON qpd.question_paper_template_detail_question_id=qptdq.id AND qpd.question_paper_id=qp.id
    INNER JOIN tc_question_mapping tcm ON tcm.tc_question_id=qpd.question_id
    INNER JOIN question_paper_evaluation qpe ON qpe.child_question_id=qptdq.id AND qpe.user_id=30 AND qpe.question_paper_id=qp.id AND qpe.tc_question_message_type_id IS NOT NULL
    INNER JOIN topic t ON t.cms_id=tcm.syllabus_chapter_details_id
    INNER JOIN chapter c ON c.id=t.chapter_id   
    IF (ChapterId IS NOT NULL)  THEN
        WHERE qp.question_paper_status_id >= 7 and c.id = ChapterId
    ELSE
        WHERE qp.question_paper_status_id >= 7
    END IF;
    GROUP BY qpe.tc_question_message_type_id LIMIT 5;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I want to add where condition according to my parameters because i have one parameter optional.
**Prob:** I dont have right syntax for that.
How can i do that. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `shashiTest`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `shashiTest`(IN GroupId INT, IN UserId INT, IN ChapterId INT)
BEGIN
    select 
    sum(qptdq.mark)-sum(qpe.marks) as marks_detucted,
    count(qpe.tc_question_message_type_id) AS noof_errors,
    (SELECT tqmt.key_value from tc_question_message_type tqmt WHERE tqmt.id=qpe.tc_question_message_type_id) AS error_type
    from question_paper qp
    INNER JOIN question_paper_group_student_map qpgsm ON qpgsm.question_paper_id=qp.id
    INNER JOIN institute_group_student_map igsm ON igsm.id=qpgsm.institute_group_student_map_id AND igsm.group_id=GroupId AND igsm.user_id=UserId
    INNER JOIN question_paper_template_detail qptd ON qptd.question_paper_template_id=qp.question_paper_template_id
    INNER JOIN question_paper_template_detail_question qptdq ON qptdq.question_paper_template_detail_id=qptd.id
    INNER JOIN question_paper_details qpd ON qpd.question_paper_template_detail_question_id=qptdq.id AND qpd.question_paper_id=qp.id
    INNER JOIN tc_question_mapping tcm ON tcm.tc_question_id=qpd.question_id
    INNER JOIN question_paper_evaluation qpe ON qpe.child_question_id=qptdq.id AND qpe.user_id=30 AND qpe.question_paper_id=qp.id AND qpe.tc_question_message_type_id IS NOT NULL
    INNER JOIN topic t ON t.cms_id=tcm.syllabus_chapter_details_id
    INNER JOIN chapter c ON c.id=t.chapter_id   
    WHERE
    CASE WHEN ChapterId IS NOT NULL THEN  //<---I had made changes at this line
         qp.question_paper_status_id >= 7 and c.id = ChapterId
    ELSE
       qp.question_paper_status_id >= 7
    END
    GROUP BY qpe.tc_question_message_type_id LIMIT 5;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

You can try above code.

I had added `CASE WHEN`.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF (ChapterId IS NOT NULL)  THEN
    WHERE qp.question_paper_status_id >= 7 and c.id = ChapterId
ELSE
    WHERE qp.question_paper_status_id >= 7
END IF;
```

You can rewrite it to

```
WHERE qp.question_paper_status_id >= 7
  AND (c.id = ChapterId OR ChapterId IS NULL)
```

No IF or CASE statement is needed here.